# How to change Labelframe border colors?

Tags: python, tkinter

I would like to be able to change a `LabelFrame` border color.
I found how to do this with a `ttk` Theme but the problem with this method is that's applying to all the `Labelframe`.

As I only want to modify one label frame I tried to using the `ttk` and `style.configure` way of doing it but it's not working. I achieved to change the label color of the label frame but the background option or the border color option doesn't seem to work.

Here is my code :
Python 3 Mac OSX

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
master = Tk()
master.geometry('200x200')
s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TLabelframe', bordercolor='red')
s.configure('TLabelframe.Label', foreground='blue')
labelframe = ttk.Labelframe(master, text='Options', style='TLabelframe')
labelframe.grid()
b = ttk.Button(labelframe, text='Hello World')
b.grid()
master.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: The options on Labelframe bordercolor, lightcolor and darkcolor are used by the clam theme. So `s.theme_use('clam')` is needed, but I guess its not what you was lookin for.

Answer (score 2):

Prepend a name to your styles, something like:

```
s.configure('User.TLabelframe', bordercolor='red')
s.configure('User.TLabelframe.Label', foreground='blue')
labelframe = ttk.Labelframe(master, text='Options', style='User.TLabelframe')
```

Comment: YEs still the same issue. The border color still doesn't change

Comment: It depends from selected theme.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Atlas435 comment, I managed to get what I want using the 'clam' theme but I don't think I can color two label frame with different color this way :

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
master = Tk()
master.geometry('800x800')

s = ttk.Style()
s.theme_use('clam')
s.configure('clam.TLabelframe', bordercolor='red', borderwidth=8,background='white')
s.configure('clam.TLabelframe.border', background='red', borderwidth=10)
s.configure('clam.TLabelframe.Label', foreground='blue',background='white')

labelframe = ttk.LabelFrame(master, text='Options', style='clam.TLabelframe',height=200, width=400)
labelframe.grid()
labelframe.grid_propagate(0)

b = ttk.Button(labelframe, text='Hello World')
b.grid()

master.mainloop()
```